# Angular routing on button clicks not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using angular routing on button clicks to route to new pages in my application. However, when I click on any of my buttons, no event is triggered and I am not directed to a new page. I have checked everything over and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

app-routing-module.ts:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CreateAccountComponent } from './create-account/create-account.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { BlushComponent } from './blush/blush.component';
import { BronzerComponent } from './bronzer/bronzer.component';
import { ConcealerComponent } from './concealer/concealer.component';
import { EyelinerComponent } from './eyeliner/eyeliner.component';
import { EyeshadowComponent } from './eyeshadow/eyeshadow.component';
import { FoundationComponent } from './foundation/foundation.component';
import { HighlighterComponent } from './highlighter/highlighter.component';
import { LipglossComponent } from './lipgloss/lipgloss.component';
import { LipstickComponent } from './lipstick/lipstick.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'create-account', component: CreateAccountComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  {path: 'loginRedirect', redirectTo: 'login'},
  {path: 'blush', component: BlushComponent},
  {path: 'bronzer', component: BronzerComponent},
  {path: 'concealer', component: ConcealerComponent},
  {path: 'eyelinder', component: EyelinerComponent},
  {path: 'eyeshadow', component: EyeshadowComponent},
  {path: 'foundation', component: FoundationComponent},
  {path: 'highlighter', component: HighlighterComponent},
  {path: 'lipgloss', component: LipglossComponent},
  {path: 'lipstick', component: LipstickComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
  

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

home.component.html:

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
 <body style="background-color:deeppink;">
    <button type="button" routerLink="['/create-account']">Create Account</button>
    <button type="button" routerLink="['/login']">Login</button>
    <button type="button" routerLink="['/about']">About</button>
 
<header>
     <h1> MakeupFinder </h1>
    <h2> What kind of product are you looking for?</h2>

</header>
<ul>

    <li *ngFor = "let makeup of makeup">
        
    <a>
        
        <button (onClick)= "click('{{makeup.name}}')">
        <img width="270px" height="280px" src= "{{makeup.imageUrl}}" >
    
        
        <div class = "content">
            <div class = "name">
            
                {{makeup.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
  
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

home.component.ts:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MakeupService} from '../services/makeup/makeup.service';
import {makeup} from '../shared/models/makeup';
import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app-routing.module';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent{
  makeup: makeup[]= [];
  constructor(private MakeupService:MakeupService, private router: Router ){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.makeup= this.MakeupService.getAll();
  }

  click(name: any){
    this.router.navigate([name]);
  }

}
```

Nothing happens when I click on my buttons

Comment: This might not be related, but your component should probably not include a `<body>` tag. Presumably this is already in your `index.html` file, so having that unique tag duplicated may cause you issues

Comment: Also I just noticed `*ngFor = "let makeup of makeup"` you are re-declaring the same variable name here. You'll need to use something different, I'm surprised this works at all for you.

Answer (score 0):

In angular the click binding should be used by adding `(click)` event handler to the element.

Here is the reference: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding#binding-to-events

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite it to this: [routerLink]="['/create-account']", dont forget the brackets, and you need to import RouterModule for the module where the component is declared, or if its standalone, in the component you can import it.